# How to use the AWS X-Ray with Nest.js?

Tags: nestjs

AWS X-Ray is support Express and Restify middleware but not support Nest.js. 
Nest.js can't open segment and close segment to AWSXRay because it routes with typescript decoration.
How to use the AWS X-Ray with the Nest.js

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, this is one of those situations that could be very interesting and difficult to work with. You can of course set up the `openSegement` call in the standard Nest middleware (looks just like Express middleware), but the `closeSegment` is a bit more difficult. I think (and I'm taking a long shot here as I have no real way to test this) you can create an interceptor and inject the `HttpAdapter` into it, check in incoming route before the request is made and see if it is a route you want to cover with X-Ray, if so mark a boolean and in the observable response (`next.handle()`) you can get the `HttpAdapter` instance and call the `closeSegment` function. In other words (and this will be really rough code):

```js
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpAdapterHost } from '@nesjts/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as xRay from 'aws-xray-sdk-express';

@Injectable
export class XRayInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly httpAdapter: HttpAdapterHost) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    let coverRoute = false;
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    if (req.path === 'yourPath') {
      coverRoute = true;
    }
    return next.handle()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => (coverRoute && this.httpAdapter.use(xRay.xrayExpress.closeSegment()))
      );
}
```

You might also probably be able to set up the `openSegment` in the interceptor as well, but again, all of this is untested and may not work as expected. I'm jsut trying to think of a way to maybe make this possible. Without access to error handling middleware your options would be to look at interceptors and filters, and it seems the `closeSegement` is to be an error handler like filters would be, so I'm not sure how you would catch errors otherwise. Maybe a filter is the best route, you may just have to play with ideas from here. Hopefully someone can give a bit more insight.